# access HTML pages using spring boot

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to serve HTML pages using spring boot , i don't want to use Thyme leaf as i just have static HTML pages note that serving js and css files is working good from /resources/static/ but if i have a controller like below

```
@Controller
public class DefaultConfiguration {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
    public ModelAndView login() {
        return new ModelAndView("login");
    }
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }


    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

i always get error

```
Circular view path [/login.html]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/login.html] again
```

Comment: Have you tried renaming the view to something else? Maybe loginview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out that i can serve html page from static folder same as javascript without having to do any controller . I was trying login because i enabled spring-security and wanted the form login to redirect to login page . the solution was simple loginpage("/login.html") but did not think of it in the first place

```
 http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/","/fonts/**","/vendors/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .and()
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to configure MvcConfiguration? If you don't have thyme leaf / free marker / vaadin on the class path wouldn't it just default to serving .html anyway?

If you have thymeleaf in ur pom.xml just take it and try have the request mapping return login without defining MVC configuration and see if that works.

Alternatively, use freemarker, not thymeleaf cos thymeleaf is kind of horrible in my opinion and save the file as login.ftl and the contents can just be pure html. Will work perfect without needing to define MVC configuration.

Comment: the idea is not to use any engine